# Closure Compiler - Could not resolve type in @extends tag

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Closure Compiler outputs a strange warning when I compile using **ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS**.

You can see it in the [Closure Compiler UI](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BIReused%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IRegistration()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IInitializable()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257BIReused%257D%2520initializer%250A%2520*%252F%250AIInitializable.prototype.initializedBy%2520%253D%2520function%2520(initializer)%2520%257B%2520%257D%253B%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BIOwned%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IReused()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IOwned()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A)

There is a warning when I compile this code using interfaces - @interface

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
 * @interface
 * @extends {IReused}
 */
function IRegistration() {
}

/**
 * @interface
 */
function IInitializable() {
}

/**
 * @param {IReused} initializer
 */
IInitializable.prototype.initializedBy = function (initializer) { };

/**
 * @interface
 * @extends {IOwned}
 */
function IReused() {
}


/**
 * @interface
 */
function IOwned() {
}
```

Output:

```
WARNING - Could not resolve type in @extends tag of IRegistration
function IRegistration() {
^
0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

But when I change all interfaces to classes using @constructor everything just works.

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {IReused}
 */
function IRegistration() {
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function IInitializable() {
}

/**
 * @param {IReused} initializer
 */
IInitializable.prototype.initializedBy = function (initializer) { };

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {IOwned}
 */
function IReused() {
}


/**
 * @constructor
 */
function IOwned() {
}
```

Also when using interfaces when I remove the IReused parameter from the initializedBy function everything works as expected.

```
/**
 * @interface
 * @extends {IReused}
 */
function IRegistration() {
}
...


/**
 * @param {IReused} initializer
 */
IInitializable.prototype.initializedBy = function (initializer) { };

To ->

/**
 * @param {*} initializer
 */
IInitializable.prototype.initializedBy = function (initializer) { };
```

Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Order you types where forward references are not required.

Comment: What do you mean by forward references not required? can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have defined `IReused` and `IOwned` after they are used in `IRegistration`.

If you just move the declerations up, it will work just fine.
Check it out in the compiler UI [here](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IOwned()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BIOwned%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IReused()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BIReused%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IRegistration()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540interface%250A%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520IInitializable()%2520%257B%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257BIReused%257D%2520initializer%250A%2520*%252F%250AIInitializable.prototype.initializedBy%2520%253D%2520function%2520(initializer)%2520%257B%2520%257D%253B%250A).

Also this is what the code looks like:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
 * @interface
 */
function IOwned() {
}

/**
 * @interface
 * @extends {IOwned}
 */
function IReused() {
}


/**
 * @interface
 * @extends {IReused}
 */
function IRegistration() {
}

/**
 * @interface
 */
function IInitializable() {
}

/**
 * @param {IReused} initializer
 */
IInitializable.prototype.initializedBy = function (initializer) { };
```

Comment: You can also generate forward declarations from your code and provide that to the compiler if it is not possible to move the declarations of the interfaces up.

Comment: Thanks, for your comment. But I don't understand why this issue comes up only when I use interfaces and not classes?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure why, but assume it has something to do with the way interfaces and classes are implemented. Interfaces might be checked more statically and earlier in the compiler passes than classes. The experts at  closure-compiler google group or github repo can probably give a more informed answer.